# Prevent non-primary key column to have duplicates

Tags: database, ms-access

I read in this site that it is recommended use an auto-number ID rather than username for primary keys because it will not change. However, how do I prevent the database to have only unique usernames. I am using Access.

Answer (score 5):

In Access, open the table in Design View and click on the `username` field. In the "Field Properties" pane at the bottom, select `Yes (No Duplicates)` for the `Indexed` property. That will prevent duplicate `username` values from being entered.

Answer (score 1):

Set unique constraint on username column (some main table for user).
You always can validate before inserting (for prompting user) or on trigger before insert.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you've already made the table, so run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE users 
ADD UNIQUE(username)
```

Change table name and column name in the query to match your table and column name, obviously.

Here's the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp